# Pattern match a string to a field

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

I have a class that has some vals to it, I need a function that returns the vals based on a string passed in

```
case class AThing(name: String, description: String)

object AThing {

  val FIRST_THING = AThing("FIRST_THING", "A first thing desc")
  val SECOND_THING = AThing("SECOND_THING", "A second thing desc")
  val THIRD_THING = AThing("THIRD_THING", "A third thing desc")

}
```

Now I have the following solution:

```
def get(name: String): AThing = {

  name match {
    case "FIRST_THING"   => FIRST_THING
    case "SECOND_THING"  => SECOND_THING
    case "THIRD_THING"   => THIRD_THING
  }

}
```

Is there a better pattern for this.. I swear I remember seeing something along the lines of this:

```
def get(name: String): AThing = {
  name match {
    case `name` => AThing.`name`
    // OR
    case `name` => AThing.{{name}}
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: The second method doesn't really apply here. The only other way I can think of finding `AThing` by name is by having the vals in a `List` and using `find`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Java reflection to get the field:

```
def get(name: String): AThing = 
  AThing.getClass.getDeclaredMethod(name).invoke(AThing).asInstanceOf[AThing]
```

As a method of `object AThing` you can also have it in this form:

```
object AThing {
  val FIRST_THING = ???
  // ... other things

  def get(name: String) = 
    this.getClass.getDeclaredField(name).get(this).asInstanceOf[AThing]
}
```

Or with Scala reflection:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror
def get(name: String) = 
  currentMirror.reflect(AThing)
               .reflectField(typeOf[AThing.type].member(TermName(name)).asTerm)
               .get.asInstanceOf[AThing]
```

To add more safety you can make it return an `Option`:

```
def getOption(name: String): Option[AThing] = util.Try(get(name)).toOption
```

But also consider modelling this concept with a `Map`:

```
object AThing {
  val things: Map[String, AThing] = Seq(
    AThing("FIRST_THING", "A first thing desc"),
    AThing("SECOND_THING", "A second thing desc"),
    AThing("THIRD_THING", "A third thing desc")
  ).map(thing => thing.name -> thing).toMap
}
```

Then you can use `AThing.things("FIRST_THING")` to get a thing by name, or to get an `Option`: `AThing.things.get("FIRST_THING")`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, ideally wouldn't want the map solution, since will mean lots of repetition, when it's a fairly simple function, will give the others a go